# Azure Table Storage Warning - WCF Data Services obsolete

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

After upgrading to the new storage API version 4.2, I'm getting the following warning that I'm calling obsolete methods on some of my segmented queries.

> 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient.GetTableServiceContext()'
>   is obsolete: 'Support for accessing Windows Azure Tables via WCF Data
>   Services is now obsolete. It's recommended that you use the
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table namespace for working with
>   tables.'

So far I haven't been able to figure out how to achieve this on the new API, and no examples have been put out that I have been able to find.  The legacy code still runs fine, but if the new API supports something better I'd love to check it out and get rid of this warning.  Could someone point me in the right direction on how a segmented query like this would look using the new API?

Here is what my code currently looks like with the warning:

```
public AzureTablePage<T> GetPagedResults<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition, string ContinuationToken, int PageSize, string TableName) {
    TableContinuationToken token = GetToken(ContinuationToken);

    var query = AzureTableService.CreateQuery<T>(TableName).Where(whereCondition).Take(PageSize).AsTableServiceQuery(AzureTableClient.GetTableServiceContext());
    var results = query.ExecuteSegmented(token, new TableRequestOptions() { PayloadFormat = TablePayloadFormat.JsonNoMetadata });
    if (results.ContinuationToken != null) {
        return new AzureTablePage<T>() { Results = results.ToList(), HasMoreResults = true, ContinuationToken = string.Join("|", results.ContinuationToken.NextPartitionKey, results.ContinuationToken.NextRowKey) };
    } else {
        return new AzureTablePage<T>() { Results = results.ToList(), HasMoreResults = false };
    }
}
public TableServiceContext AzureTableService {
    get {
        var context = AzureTableClient.GetTableServiceContext();
        context.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true;
        return context;
     }
}
public CloudTableClient AzureTableClient {
    get {
        return mStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    }
}
```

**Solution**

For anyone with the same question, here is the updated code.

```
    /* Add the following Using Statement */
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Queryable;

    public AzureTablePage<T> GetPagedResults<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition, string ContinuationToken, int PageSize, string TableName) where T : class, ITableEntity, new() {
        TableContinuationToken token = GetToken(ContinuationToken);
        var query = AzureTableClient.GetTableReference(TableName).CreateQuery<T>().Where(whereCondition).Take(PageSize).AsTableQuery();
        var results = query.ExecuteSegmented(token, new TableRequestOptions() { PayloadFormat = TablePayloadFormat.JsonNoMetadata });
        if (results.ContinuationToken != null) {
        return new AzureTablePage<T>() { Results = results.ToList(), HasMoreResults = true, ContinuationToken = string.Join("|", results.ContinuationToken.NextPartitionKey, results.ContinuationToken.NextRowKey) };
    } else {
        return new AzureTablePage<T>() { Results = results.ToList(), HasMoreResults = false };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [Tables Deep Dive blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx) that we published when we first introduced the new Table Service Layer. If you need LINQ support, please also see the [Azure Storage Client Library 2.1 blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/announcing-storage-client-library-2-1-rtm.aspx).

We strongly recommend upgrading to Table Service Layer, because it is optimized for NoSQL scenarios and therefore provides much better performance.

Comment: When creating a TableQuery and passing it an expression parameter Expression<Func<T, bool>>, the return object is of type IQueryable.  The problem I run into is ExecuteQuerySegmented doesn't accept  IQueryable as a parameter, it needs a TableQuery.  Could you provide an example of how this could work? The blog post provided did not cover this scenario

Comment: Similar to AsTableServiceQuery you used in the sample code above, there is an AsTableQuery helper method to get back a TableQuery. Please let us know if that works for you.

Comment: The AsTableQuery helper did the trick.  For those who need this, add Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Queryable to your using statements